# Concurrency issues with spring application cache and autowired instance

Tags: java, spring-mvc, concurrency, static, autowired

I have the following app level cache in a spring MVC application

```
@Service
class ApplicationConfig {
  @Autowired 
  ConfigClass instance;

  static ConfigClass configCache;

  @PostConstruct  @Lazy
  void init() {
    configCache = instance;
  }

  static String getAttribute(String key) {
    return configCache.getProperty(key);
  }
}
```

and the ConfigClass is defined as below :

```
@Service
class ConfigClass {

  volatile boolean cacheValid = false;

  void initCache() { // called once after server startup - contextRefreshedEvent
    refreshCache();
    // after initCache is completed a job is scheduled to run refreshCache every 30 minutes
  }

  synchronized void refreshCache(){
    cacheValid = false;
    //assign a Map from DB
    cacheValid = true;
  }

  String getAttribute(String key) {
    // spin till cacheValid is true 
    return map.get(key);
  }
}
```

CacheValid is not defined anywhere , but still after server startup , getAttribute() method is stuck and and spins because cacheValid is false.
Why is cacheValid false after server startup ?
IS the issue because of 2 instances of ConfigClass ? and for one instance initCache is not executed or am I missing anything ?
This was working fine, recently new application class loaders were changed , after which the issue started appearing regularly

Comment: Where are you calling `initCache`? Have you tried adding the `@PostConstruct` annotation to `initCache`?

Comment: init cache is called after server startup using the  contextRefreshedEvent

Comment: Have you tried adding `@PostConstruct` to the method?

Comment: initCache along with initCache  for multiple caches is called after context refresh , that means it is definitely post the initialization of ConfigClass Bean.
All other caches work fine , only this bean with the static to instance initialisation is not working ,

Comment: Have you tried adding the annotation to the method? If not, try it.

Comment: hi  Unmitigated 
if I add , initCache will be called twice
this issue never happens in the local env , only in the UAT envs 
I cannot try something in the UAT envs , need to know why this issue happens before trying something