# Spring multiple autowired singleton instances

Tags: java, spring, static, instance, autowired

Will spring create multiple instances of `ActualService` in the following scenario, `ActualService` is a singleton `@Service`.

```java
@Service
class ServiceStatic {
    
    @Autowired
    ActualService instance;
    
    static ActualService staticInstance;
    
    @PostConstruct @Lazy
    void init() {
        staticInstance = instance;
    }
    
    static String someStaticMethod() {
        return staticInstance.someMethod()
    }
}
```

In my code I see the staticInstance does not have fields initialized whereas `ActualService` instance has fields initialized. Can someone explain.

Comment: Some line breaks and better formatting of the code would be helpful. After that being said, what you are trying to do doesn't make sense. Why use static at all here?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `@LazyInit` annotation? I don't know what it is, you can use Spring's `@Lazy` annotation.

Comment: Thanks , It is @Lazy , I have updated my comment.
 'ServiceStatic.someStaticMethod()' is a public static method already used  in multiple places , I am using the static method to actually call the instance method , ie,  'ActualService instance .someMethod()'

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to inject a static bean is to use setter injection. Something like this:

```
@Service
class ServiceStatic {
    
    @Autowired
    ActualService instance;
    
    static ActualService staticInstance;
    
    @Autowired
    public void setStaticInstance(  ActualService instance ){
      staticInstance = instance;
    }
}
```

The `static` section is evaluated before beans creation so you will have `null` instance there. You can also extract a bean directly from the `ApplicationContext` instead of doing such strange thing.

Comment: are there chances of 2 instances created in the way I have posted
https://stackoverflow.com/q/68668961/16593066

Comment: @abdullaha As you said, it's a `Singleton` bean, by definition a singleton does not have multiple instances. If you need multiple instances, change the scope of your bean.

Comment: I know this is a singleton instance and the static section can have bull value, but I am debugging an issue, both the instance and the static instance have different fields set, thats why I have raised the question - is there a chance of 2 instances getting created

Comment: I don’t know neither your settings nor your application but there isn’t any chance to have 2 different instances of a singleton bean.

Comment: the problem in my code is described here :  https://stackoverflow.com/q/68653016/16593066